# Most distinct goal scorers in a team to start the NHL playoffs

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

The Las Vegas Golden Knights Swept the Los Angeles Kings in the first round of the 2017-2018 Stanley Cup playoffs. In those 4 games, the Golden Knights scored 7 goals, by 7 different players.

This makes me wonder what's the most number of different goal scorers any team has ever had to start the an NHL playoffs?